# Magento2 DOC area type

Tags: magento2, area

I was checking about the different areas in magento2 and found AREA_CODE = doc. Does anyone know the purpose of it?[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2, the AREA_CODE constant is used to specify the area code for a particular module. The area code is used to distinguish between different areas of a Magento installation, such as the frontend (customer facing) or backend (admin facing) areas.

The doc area code is used to specify the documentation area of a Magento installation. This area code is used to identify and manage the documentation resources and files that are used in a Magento installation.

The area code is used in conjunction with other Magento components, such as layout files and templates, to specify which resources and files should be used for a particular area of the Magento installation. For example, a layout file or template that is specified for the doc area code will only be used for the documentation area of the Magento installation.

It's worth noting that the doc area code is not used by default in a Magento installation. It is only used if you have installed a module or extension that utilizes this area code.